# Access Child View from List Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to highlight an item in a `ListView` (touchable interface). The aim is that the user will touch an image and it will select the item in the `ListView` moving it to be visible (it does not all show on the screen at the same time) and then highlight the item in the `ListView` related to the position on the image by changing the background color of the item view.  I have a custom `ListAdapter` with a view for each item.

From the image I can get the postion of the item in the `ListView`.  From this I can call `listView.setSelection(selectedPos)`.  This positions the item at the top of the list.  However I now want to get the view for this item; I have tried `getFirstVisiblePosition()` however it seems that this is not available until the list has been layed out (I am responding to a click on the image) so I cannot use this.

Nothing else I try works - all I want to do is to do something like `listView.getViewAt(index)` but I simply cannot find a way of doing it.  I cannot use 'selected' as I am in touchable mode.

For what seems a very simple thing - I've wasted a day; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: Does [getSelectedView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getSelectedView()) have the same problem?

Comment: getSelectedView always returns null if you interface is touchable :(

Comment: I've tried caching the views in the adapter but Android changes them underneath me so I cannot use that either!  For such a simple request this is silly; I'm totally stuck here and it shoud be an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got round this by doing the following:

- I marked the item I wished to select in the adapter first by adding in my own method
- Then when the view is requested I can check to see if the view is for a position at which I requested
- I get then modify the presented view that is returned by GetView

  This seems the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `listView.getChildAt(position)` do what you want?

Comment: Unfortunatly not; get childAt only gives me the views that have been created by ListView - not all the views in teh entire list view.  If I need a view that has not been created as yet (it seems to only create the views when I need it) then I cannot access the views - these views are not made until the call to make the listview has finished and I have no idea when that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own custom adapter for the list view.  For example:

```
 private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {
       public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<RowData> objects) { 
            super(context, resource, objects);
       }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            //convertView holds the view for each item.
            TextView txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            //do some other stuff with the views
            return convertView;
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot do that as I don't know if the listview has a view already and therefore cannot supply a convert view.  This means that I won't necessarily be accessing the view that is on the screen.